# Idiom for making up a false story as an excuse to get out of something

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

An idiom that means to make up stories or excuses, especially those that are not true, and are just false excuses you give when you try to justify/save yourself.

Maybe similar to feeding crap/bullsh**

Comment: not feeding, shoveling. [linky](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shovel-shit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an idiom, **["pretext"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pretext)** seems to fit

> A reason or excuse given to hide the real reason for something,  a fictitious reason given in order to conceal the real one. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pretext)

It was a pretext for not joining us.

Comment: Op asks for an idiom, although after seeing your answer one should change their mind.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is from the point of view of the person to whom the excuse is given:
***fairy tale***

> John told me another **fairy tale** about why he can't finish repairing the car until next week.

**fairy tale** from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fairy-tale)

> A fabricated story, especially one intended to deceive

Answer (score 2):

An idiomatic expression is to tell ***[a cock-and-bull story](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+cock-and-bull+story)*** :

> - a story or explanation which is obviously not true.
>
>   - *She told me some cock-and-bull story about her car breaking down.*

(Cambridge Idioms Dictionary,)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few:

> fob someone off [with some excuse]
>
> brush someone off [with some excuse]

Answer (score 0):

Although not explicitly stated anywhere, [spin a yarn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spin_a_yarn) has some connotations of very slight deception, in that someone spinning a yarn wants the listener to believe what they have to convey.

> To tell or create a story, especially one which is far-fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this as a ***[song and dance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/song%20and%20dance):***

> a long and often familiar statement or explanation that is usually not true or pertinent

(Merriam-Webster)

Comment: Normally *song and dance* is used as a metaphor for giving too much publicity to something. *I wouldn't make a song and dance about how much money you won, otherwise you will have the world descending on you for a hand-out*.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use "fibbing" here.

> From WordNet (r) 3.0 (2006) [wn]:
>
> fib
>        n 1: a trivial lie; "he told a fib about eating his spinach";
>             "how can I stop my child from telling stories?" [syn:
>             {fib}, {story}, {tale}, {tarradiddle}, {taradiddle}]
>        v 1: tell a relatively insignificant lie; "Fibbing is not
>             acceptable, even if you don't call it lying"

Comment: We don't know if the OP was referring to a trivial lie - a fib - or a lie.